# Christian Orthodox Cemeteries in Philadelphia

Tags: pennsylvania, 1920s, cemeteries

In which cemetery would Christian (Albanian) Orthodoxes be buried in Philadelphia in the 1920s? Would they be buried in standard, i.e. protestant, sites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen [Brief History of St. John Chrysostom Albanian Orthodox Church](http://www.stjohnsphila.org/history.html) & [SS. Peter and Paul Church, Uniondale PA](https://oca.org/parishes/oca-ep-undspp)? Dedicated church cemeteries seem to have been the norm, but they also used sections within larger non-denominational cemeteries.

Which congregation an immigrant joined often depended on what was convenient for worship. Slight differences in church custom and liturgy between various national churches could be overcome if there weren't enough of a specfic group in a city or a neighbourhood to sustain a parish.

Comment: I did, St John Chrysostom is more recent (they mention a Serbian Orthodox Church which their congregants went earlier-- probably St Nicholas). The one in Uniondale is too remote. I have researched the st Nicholas church but Albanians seemed only sporadic.

Comment: I had checked the Uniondale church's page because the St. John history mentioned an earlier SS. Peter & Paul Orthodox church in Philadelphia and kept the link because of the references to the cemetery.

Comment: I located the SS Peter and Paul church in Philadelphia, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Anesti Zoto, founding member of St. John Chrysostom had his funeral there and was buried in Lawnview Cemetery in Rockledge, according to his obituary found in the July 24, 1993 issue of Philadelphia Inquirer.